# .Net MVC not sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I'm am trying to follow Microsoft's tutorials on sorting for .net MVC5, and while the filtering is working fine, the sorting is not.

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString, string currentFilter, string numberPerPage, string submit, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = string.IsNullOrEmpty(numberPerPage) ? 10 : Int32.Parse(numberPerPage);
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var CohortList = from s in db.Cohorts select s;
        if (((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString)) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFilter))) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(submit)))
        {
            if (SearchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                SearchString = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = SearchString;
            ViewBag.numberPerPage = numberPerPage;
            switch (submit)
            {
                case "conceptSearch":
                    var conceptResults = CohortList.Where(s => s.Overview.Contains(SearchString)).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    if (conceptResults.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchTerm = SearchString;
                        ViewBag.submit = submit;
                        return View(conceptResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchTerm = SearchString;
                        ViewBag.submit = submit;
                        return View(conceptResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
                    }
                    //break;
                case "textSearch":
                    var textResults = CohortList.Where(s => s.Overview.Contains(SearchString)).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    if (textResults.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchTerm = SearchString;
                        ViewBag.submit = submit;
                        return View(textResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.searchTerm = SearchString;
                        ViewBag.submit = submit;
                        return View(textResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
                    }
                    //break;
            }
        }
        return View(CohortList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

The paging works fine, but it always returns a list that is sorted by ID and not by name.

Comment: Why is your numberPerPage parameter a string? It should be a nullable int.

Comment: Can you give more example with data?

Comment: I would bet that your if statement does not work and you getting results  from the last return statement. If only you debugged the code...

Comment: Your code is too much duplicated. The if/else is redundant because the code in the block is the same for the if and the else.

Comment: @Reniuz What do you mean by debug the code?  I'm brand new at this and do not know what you mean.  When i compile, there aren't any errors.

Comment: @yondaimehokage then you started to learn from the wrong spot. You know how to compile code, next step - [breakpoints and debugging your code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ab4z9u7Q_I). And in short put the breakpoint on if line, hit start debug a(F5) and when you hit breakpoint, move mouse over variables and use step over (F10) to navigate to next line.

Comment: Debug your code! You clearly not entering any of the `case` statements because the value of `submit` is not either `"conceptSearch"` or `"textSearch"` (and you have not even shown how your view passes a value for that parameter)

Comment: The queries you are writing do end with `.OrderBy(s => s.Name)` which is good, if you add a `.ToList()` to them at that point, you should get sorted data. *But*, in your code above you then call a `.ToPagedList(..)` method and we cannot see what happens to the `IQueryable` inside that method. Could you please include the contents of that method in your question?